# Load data on Spring Boot application startup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servletcontextlistener

I wish to load some data on application-startup and store them in a global context so that all my configuration and controller classes can read those data from the context.

Traditionally, I use a `ServletContextListener` to load the data in `contextInitialized` method and store them in `ServletContext`. For example,

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // load data
    event.getServletContext()..setAttribute(...)
}
```

And in my controllers I just inject the `ServletContext` or make my controller implement `ServletContextAware`.

What is the Spring Boot way of achieving this? I can think of the below options, but not completely sure how to use these for my use-case.

- `@PostConstruct` (on which bean?)
- `@Configuration` (load the data and return as a `@Bean`?)
- `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` that listens on `ContextRefreshedEvent` or `ApplicationReadyEvent` (how to expose the data to my controllers? I also want the data on my `@Configuration` class. But these events occur after beans defined in `@Configuration` are already created)

Comment: What kind of data do you want to make available? Is it some kind of configurations or is it data related to your domain?

Comment: In addition to @DanyloZatorsky question: where do you fetch the data from? DB, HTTP, something else?

Comment: Configuration data from an HTTP service.